# Timing issue when animating custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I'm having an issue with my application architecture...

I have a `UITableView` filled with custom `UITableViewCells`.
Of course, I use dequeuing so there are only 8-10 cell instances ever generated.

Moving forward to my problem... I have added a theming feature to my application.
When the user long touches the main `UINavigationBar`a notification is posted app wide that informs each viewController to update their UI.

When the viewController hosting the tableView with the custom cells receives the notification, it calls `tableView.reloadData()`

This works well, as I have implemented `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Inside `willDisplay` I call a method on my custom tableViewCell which animates, using `UIViewAnimation`, appropriate colour changes to the cell.

It looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let newsFeedItemCell = cell as? NewsFeedItemCell {
        if (self.nightModeEnabled) {
            newsFeedItemCell.transitionToNightMode()
        } else {
            newsFeedItemCell.transitionFromNightMode()
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the custom cell implementation those methods look like this:

```
func transitionToNightMode() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            self.titleTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            self.titleTextView.textColor = UIColor.white
        })
}

func transitionFromNightMode() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.titleTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.titleTextView.textColor = UIColor.black
    })
}
```

This works fine... heres the issue:

Upon scrolling the tableView, **any cells that weren't on screen** have their colour update/animation code called **as they scroll onto the screen**, which leads to a jarring user experience.

I understand why this is happening of course, as `willDisplay` is only called as cells display.

I can't think of an elegant way to avoid this.

I'm happy that cells **on screen** are animating for the user experience to be pleasant, however, for cells off screen, I'd rather they *skipped* the animation.

---

**Possible solutions (though inelegant):**

Keep a reference to each of the 8-10 cells created by `cellForRow`, and check if they are off screen, if they are set their state immediately.

However, I don't like the idea of keeping a reference to each cell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use a `reloadData` to animate this, since your data model for the tableview is not actually changing.

Instead, I would give the UITableView a function, like so:

```
class myClass : UITableViewController {
    ....

    func transitionToNightMode() {
            for visible in visibleCells {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                visible.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                visible.titleTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                visible.titleTextView.textColor = UIColor.white
            })
            }
    }
}
```

and then in your willDisplay or cellForItemAt, set the correct appearance without animation.

Comment: Delightful solution. It's OK to call against visible cells? reload should only be called to change data right ?

Comment: @Woodstock thanks! Yes, this is fine to call against visible cells. The visible cells are part of the hierarchy like any other UIViews. I sometimes get lazy and use reload when I really don't need to, but it is generally there for changes in the data model, not simply for visual appearance.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following.

Instead of using `UIView.animate`, in `transition(To/From)NightMode` I would create a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` object that would do the same animation. I would keep the reference to that object around and then in prepare for reuse, if the animation is still running, I would simply finish that animation and reset the state. So something like this:

```
fileprivate var transitionAnimator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?

fileprivate func finishAnimatorAnimation() {
    // if there is a transitionAnimator, immediately finishes it
    if let animator = transitionAnimator {
        animator.stopAnimation(false)
        animator.finishAnimation(at: .end)
        transitionAnimator = nil
    }
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    finishAnimatorAnimation()
}

func transitionToNightMode() {
    transitionAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.titleTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.titleTextView.textColor = UIColor.white
    })
    transitionAnimator?.startAnimation()
}

func transitionFromNightMode() {
    transitionAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.titleTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.titleTextView.textColor = UIColor.black
    })
    transitionAnimator?.startAnimation()
}
```